# Aggregate, Sum and Round altogether

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregate, rounding

So far I have tried

```
  return self.aggregate(round(Sum("cart__total"),2), Avg("cart__total"))
  return self.aggregate(Sum(round("cart__total")),Avg("cart__total"))
  return (self.aggregate(
    (round(Sum("cart__total"),2)),
    (round(Avg("cart__total"),2))))
  recent_data = '{:0.2f}'.format(recent_data)
  recent_data = format(recent_data, '.2f')
```

When I do

```
<p>Recent Total: ${{ this_week.recent_data.cart__total__sum }}</p>
```

I get

```
Recent Total: ${'cart__total__sum': Decimal('146238.770000000'), 'cart__total__avg': Decimal('16248.7522222222')}
```

I want to round the decimals to two places.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
return self.aggregate(Sum("cart__total"),Avg("cart__total"))
```

Your template:

```
<p>Recent Total: ${{ this_week.recent_data.cart__total__sum|floatformat:2 }}</p>
```

See [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) from django docs.